# How can I see Jenkins failed tests statcktrace in Netbeans?

Tags: svn, netbeans, junit, jenkins

I am running Netbeans 7.2 + Subversion 1.7 + Jenkins 1.466.2 on Ubuntu 12.04.
The Hudson/Jenkins plugin in Netbeans says: "This subversion working copy is not supported", so I managed to configure my project under Jenkins under "Build a free-style software project". I also added Jenkins as a Hudson instance in "Hudson Builders" in the Services section, and I set the build to be related to my project and set it to be watched.
In the build process I added a call to the "test" Ant task, so JUnit tests run in each build, and I can see the failed tests in Jenkins. Netbeans is also informed that the build failed, and I can see the results in the output window, along with the stacktrace.
What I would like to have is the tests results displayed in the "Test Results" window, so I can click on the stacktrace of the failed tests and navigate to the line that caused the problem. My instinct says there should be a way to do that, but my brain is burnt after spending the whole weekend configuring everything.
Does anyone know if this is possible and how to do it?
Thanks!